# How to pass an additional parameter with spring security login page

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to set the database name as the request input parameter from the spring security login page. At present I am only getting username that's been retrieved using spring security `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`.

How to access the additional field that's been set on the login page?

Comment: Do you want to pass this parameter before login or get parameters after login from DB?

Comment: i want to get the request parameter value before connecting to DB, i wanted to decide which DB the user needs to get connected based upon the select values provided on the login screen.

Comment: I dont think, Spring have capability to do it out of box. Anyway, you can create our own authentication filter and get this parameter from `HttpRequest` object.

Comment: Lookt at the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. It is used by default on any login page.

Comment: yes i am trying to work it out that way. But i missing some part over there and running into errors. Please Let me know if you have some idea or working sample (configuration) of it.

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using?

Comment: may be your are looking for [this](http://naeemgik.blogspot.com/2018/10/passing-extra-login-fields-with-spring.html)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Elaborating on @Vacuum's comment

Here's a simple way (untested, but I believe this would work)

1. Create a new class `ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` that will extend the default filter and grab the additional parameter and store it in the session. It will look something like this:

```java
public class ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        final String dbValue = request.getParameter("dbParam");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("dbValue", dbValue);

        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response); 
    } 
}
```

2. In your `UserDetailsService` implementation, modify your implementation of:

```java
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException;
```

to grab the session variable that the filter from step 1) makes available.

3. in your `<http />` security set-up, override the default filter with your custom one

```xml
<custom-filter ref="beanForYourCustomFilterFromStep1" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
```

Refer to this part of the documentation for more info about custom filters: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. I implemented it, it worked well.

Comment: There is less invasive way of doing this and without violating the contract of `UserDetailsService`. I agree with @sourcedelica. Also eee my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16155696/719633) to similar question for more detailed example.

Comment: @Bhas, how did you modified UserDetailsService to grab the session variable?

Answer (score 47):

There's a number of ways to do this but the official way to do it is using a custom `AuthenticationDetails` and `AuthenticationDetailsSource`, subclassing Spring's [`WebAuthenticationDetails`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetails.html) and [`WebAuthenticationDetailsSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetailsSource.html), respectively.   Add the extra field to the custom `WebAuthenticationDetails` and have the custom `WebAuthenticationDetailsSource` get the data from the request to populate the field.

In Spring Security 3.1 it's easy to configure by using the `authentication-details-source-ref` attribute of the `<form-login>` element.

In 3.0 you have to use a `BeanPostProcessor`.  There is an example in the Spring Security FAQ on [using a BeanPostProcessor to configure a custom WebAuthenticationDetailsSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-namespace-post-processor).

Once this is done then you can call SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails() to get access to your extra field.

Comment: Thanks Ericacm, The have implemented the solution provided by Taylor Mingos and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, for the custom AuthenticationDetails idea. This is interesting. You say it's official, but I can't find any official documentation about that technique. Is there any?

Comment: There's not much documentation - you have to infer it from how the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` works - it uses a `WebAuthenticationDetailsSource` and adds a `WebAuthenticationDetails` to the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

Answer (score 23):

[sourcedelica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10078692/3151168) mentioned using `AuthenticationDetailsSource` and a custom `AuthenticationDetails`.
Here is an example.

Add `authentication-details-source-ref` attribute with the bean id `customWebAuthenticationDetailsSource` to `form-login`:

```
<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="..." />
    <security:form-login authentication-details-source-ref="customWebAuthenticationDetailsSource" login-page="..." />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="..." />
</security:http>
```

Create a new class `CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource`:

```
package security;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource implements AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, WebAuthenticationDetails> {
    @Override
    public WebAuthenticationDetails buildDetails(HttpServletRequest context) {
        return new CustomWebAuthenticationDetails(context);
    }
}
```

and the related `CustomWebAuthenticationDetails`:

```
package security;

import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class CustomWebAuthenticationDetails extends WebAuthenticationDetails {

    private final String yourParameter;

    public CustomWebAuthenticationDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        yourParameter = request.getParameter("yourParameter");
    }

    public String getyourParameter() {
        return yourParameter;
    }

    //TODO override hashCode, equals and toString to include yourParameter
    @Override
    public int hashCode() { /* collapsed */ }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { /* collapsed */ }
    @Override
    public String toString() { /* collapsed */ }
}
```

Comment: then How can I use the **CustomWebAuthenticationDetails** ?

Comment: see @sourcedelica answer: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()`

Comment: Did not work for me. The AuthenticationDetailsSource calls buildDetails after the login and my GET parameter is not there anymore. Using Spring 3.1.6

Comment: @raupach There must be something wrong with your security configuration. If you like you can grab my example from [Github](https://github.com/ksokol/spring-sandbox/blob/master/spring-mvc/src/main/resources/security.xml) for debugging.

Comment: @ksokol Yes, my bad. The parameter is available in the post request not in the initial get request. I now set the get paramaters I need as input hidden and then it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the example @ksokol, it works mostly fine for me but while getting the details, the context is null. I need the extra parameter to perform a custom query by overriding JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername(String username). Any idea of how to get the extra parameter at that point?

Comment: @diegosahagun While calling `JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername` yet the `SecurityContext` is not populated with the current `Authentication`, hence `null` reference. In your case you need a custom `AuthenticationProvider` which is capable of handling your extra parameter. In that case you can't `UserDetailsService`. Maybe you can elaborate on your problem in a separate question and receive multiple answers.

Answer (score 9):

There is an easier way if you are using custom `AuthenticationProvider`. You can just inject `HttpServletRequest` and retrieve your extra parameter:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    private MyAccountService myAccountService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {

        System.out.println("request testing= " + request.getParameter("testing"));

        .....
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@user1322340 does not provide implement detail to get session Attributes in loadUserByUsername function:

Step 1: Follow all the step provided by @user1322340

Step 2: 
you need add one configuration in web.xml like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
       org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Step 3:
Use such code to get attributes:

```
RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().getAttribute("yourAttributeName", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
```

Step 4: Register your filter in spring security config. 
If you get a error "**authenticationManager must be specified**". after you register your filter in config. You need set a authenticationManagerBean for your extended filter and config it in that way:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter exUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter()
            throws Exception {
        ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter exUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        exUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
                .setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return exUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        RequestMatcher requestMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
                if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().indexOf("/api", 0) >= 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

        http
                .addFilterBefore(exUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For spring security 3.0 or above which uses java configuration, the following simple steps works well.

- Add a your of filter before the
  UserNameandPasswordAuthenticationFilter in HttpSecurity object in configure.

  ```
  http.addFilterBefore(new YourFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  ```
- Let the filter has a line like this to get the needed fields in your
  request to session.

  ```
  if(requestPath != null &&requestPath.equals("/login") ) {
          session.setAttribute("yourParam",req.getParameter("yourParam"));
      }
  ```
- Later you may get the parameter value from the session in any class as:

  ```
  String yourParam =(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("yourParam");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

1) register RequestContextListener

```
@Bean
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
    return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

2) And to main class:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.
currentRequestAttributes()).
getRequest();
```

3) After that we can take params in custom headers:

```
request.getHeader("OrganizationId")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way in only 2 steps:

**Step 1.**

Add the following listener in web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Step 2.**

Add the following in your class method where you want to get additional param:

```
RequestAttributes attribs = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null) {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) attribs).getRequest();
}
```

Now you can get your additional parameter by the following, assuming the extra parameter is named "loginType":

```
request.getParameter("loginType")
```