# passing extra params when login with grails spring security plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

I’m writing a web service for a mobile application with grails. 
I use spring security core 
To login I call **/j_spring_security_check** , and send **j_username** , **j_password**

Then in Ajax Success method of the login controller I return the sessionId

```
springSecurityService.authentication.details.sessionId
```

How can I pass extra params when I do the login

Comment: Implementing a customer `AuthenticationProvider` would probably be the easiest way.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104228/how-implement-spring-security-when-login-page-having-more-field-apart-from-user/16155696#16155696.