# Additional field in login using Grails Spring Security plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

My question is similar to this one

[How to pass an additional parameter with spring security login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074308/how-to-pass-an-additional-parameter-with-spring-security-login-page)

though it applies to Grails Spring Security plugin. If I have to support an additional field in login (company name) , how do I do it in Grails?

I will get the company name field from the URL.

For example.
/login?companyname=c1
/login?companyname=c2

The same user name can be used by different users in different companies. So user name is not unique but user name + company name is unique.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not nice solution but you can join username and company name into single username field. For example `oneUser_company1`, `oneUser_company2`. In that case, you would have to create multiple accounts for single user.

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, but I would rather not use this solution.Found another one -http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1090 Going to try this and report back. Thanks to Burt Beckwith! His book is good too!

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this custom filter](http://oavatos.org/2011/03/26/custom-security-filter-for-grails-spring-security-3-plugin/) is a start point.

Probably you will need a custom `AuthenticationToken` to store your company name, instead of using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

You will need an [AuthenticationProvider](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/10%20Authentication%20Providers.html) too, since you will need to get your user by username and company.

The flow will be:

- Filter will create your custom `AuthenticationToken`, storing the company field.
- Your custom `AuthenticationProvider` will get this token and try to load the user by username and company
- Spring Security Core will check your password