# Add extra parameter in login page in spring security using Authenticationprovider

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I want to pass extra parameter in my login page. My application context looks like this.
For example I want to add `location` parameter in login form.

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myetest.app" />

<sec:http entry-point-ref="apiAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="always">
    <sec:form-login login-processing-url="/login" 
        username-parameter="username" 
        password-parameter="password" 
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="apiAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="apiLoginSuccessHandler" />
    <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="apiLogoutSuccessHandler"/>

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/receipt/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/internal/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/system/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_SELLER"/>

    <sec:custom-filter ref="apiPreAuthFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="apiFirstFilter" before="LAST"/>
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="apiAuthenticationProvider"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="apiAuthenticationProvider" class="com.myetest.app.security.ApiAuthenticationProvider" />
<bean id="apiAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.myetest.app.security.ApiAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
<bean id="apiLoginSuccessHandler" class="com.myetest.app.security.ApiLoginSuccessHandler"/>
<bean id="apiLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.myetest.app.security.ApiLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
<bean id="apiAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.myetest.app.security.ApiAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
<bean id="apiPreAuthFilter" class="com.myetest.app.security.ApiPreAuthenticationFilter" />

<bean id="apiFirstFilter" class="com.myetest.app.security.ApiFirstFilter"/>
```

My `AuthenticationProvider` is like this.

```
public class ApiAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at [possible solution (section 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077700/2964811) and here some [explanation](http://mrather.blogspot.com/2010/02/extending-usernamepasswordauthenticatio.html). Solution is based at [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) usage. 
Briefly, you can override `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` where you can extract `location` from `HttpServletRequest` body in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication` and do some your custom stuff. Or you can add custom MVC controller that will accept your form data and manually invoke there `AuthenticationManager` with yours custome `AuthenticationProvider`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for response. After overriding the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to read extra parameter. It would be great if you could also help me the changes required in applicationcontext.xml. Currently I am doing my authentication in ApiAuthenticationProvider class. It would be great if you provide code here.