# Keeping additional login form parameters between login failures

Tags: spring-security

I have Spring security login from with additional parameters passed to it(by extending WebAuthenticationDetailsSource, and WebAuthenticationDetails. Moreover login page also includes Recaptcha validation, here my problem is if either login or Recaptcha fails the additional parameters get lost. Note the additional parameters are passed to login page only once and I have no way to get them back if failure occurs(due to incorrect username, password, or else captcha). Is there a way to preserve additional parameters between mentioned failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074308/how-to-pass-an-additional-parameter-with-spring-security-login-page) will likely lead you towards your solution of implementing your own filter to capture these prior to authentication and storing them in the session.