# Java Config Spring Security FORM_LOGIN_FILTER

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working through some of the Spring Security tutorials and trying to implement them without xml and I can't seem to find a anything about replacing the default **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter**.

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074308/how-to-pass-an-additional-parameter-with-spring-security-login-page/10077700#10077700) I'd like to retrieve an extra parameter from the login form. Where I'm having difficulty is:

```
<custom-filter ref="customAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
```

In order to set this up properly do I need to build from the AuthenticationManagerBuilder down? or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. Looks like there aren't many who have done this before.

Answer (score 16):

According to the Spring Security documentation found here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#filter-stack

FORM_LOGIN_FILTER is just an alias for the class UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

So

```
http.addFilterBefore(new YourFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Am I missing it or are you simply adding a filter before the default? I was under the impression the XML config allowed you to replace it.

Comment: to replace the default use addFilterAt method

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Juan for good doc link. But you must use `addFilterAt` instead of `addFilterBefore`.

So, this is correct :

```
http.addFilterAt(new YourFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

This will replace the existing default implementation with your CustomFilter.