# How to use custom filter with authentication-success-handler-ref equivalent in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to pass some parameters with login details to spring security such as some item id.
then after i want to redirect to page according to the user type.
For this i am using **custom filter** to send additional parameter.
And to redirection i am using **authentication-success-handler-ref**.
My problem is, I am geting position conflict as i am using  along with **custom filter**.
Please help me out to do my task.

Here is my configuration

```
<http   use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />

       <custom-filter ref="ddAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <form-login authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" 
        authentication-success-handler-ref="ddAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>



    </http>

    <beans:bean id="ddAuthenticationFilter" class="com.dd.security.ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"/>

    <beans:bean id="ddAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.dd.security.DDAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understood your question as follows: *I want to submit an itemId in the form login which is used after a successful login for redirection*.

In order to establish such a process you need to do following things.

Remove `<form-login ...>` from your configuration. You should have:

```
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />

    <custom-filter ref="ddAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:logout />
</http>
```

Don't forget to add a `<security:logout />` for logout and the `entry-point-ref` attribute points to an `authenticationEntryPoint`.

Add a `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` for `entry-point-ref` which points to your login page:

```
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
</bean>
```

Refactor your `ddAuthenticationFilter` to meet the following configuration:

```
<bean id="ddAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="ddAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <property name="authenticationDetailsSource">
        <bean class="security.CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/accessdenied" />
</bean>
```

Create a new class `CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource`:

```
package security;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource implements AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, WebAuthenticationDetails> {
    @Override
    public WebAuthenticationDetails buildDetails(HttpServletRequest context) {
        return new CustomWebAuthenticationDetails(context);
    }
}
```

and the related `CustomWebAuthenticationDetails`:

```
package security;

import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class CustomWebAuthenticationDetails extends WebAuthenticationDetails {

    private final String itemId;

    public CustomWebAuthenticationDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        itemId = request.getParameter("itemId");
    }

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    //TODO override hashCode, equals and toString to include itemId
    @Override
    public int hashCode() { /* collapsed */ }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { /* collapsed */ }
    @Override
    public String toString() { /* collapsed */ }
}
```

Your `ddAuthenticationSuccessHandler` should have a similiar logic like in this example:

```
package com.dd.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DDAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        CustomWebAuthenticationDetails details = (CustomWebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
        if(StringUtils.hasText(details.getItemId())) {
            //TODO sanity and security check for itemId needed
            String redirectUrl = "item/" + details.getItemId();
            response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("itemId in authentication details not found");
    }
}
```

A working example can be found [here](https://github.com/ksokol/spring-sandbox/tree/custom-data-spring-security)

Comment: After some reading I discovered that since Spring 3.1 you could simplify your configuration by using authentication-details-source-ref on form-login node. [Take alook here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074308/how-to-pass-an-additional-parameter-with-spring-security-login-page/23968778#23968778)

Comment: @ksokol hi very usefull but its shows me "Failed to convert property value of type  
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' to required   
    type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationDetailsSource' for property 'authenticationDetailsSource';" can u plz tell what i am doing wrong

Comment: @Anurag Unfortunately your description is too vague to help you. You should post your Spring Security configuration, a stacktrace and a guide how to reproduce your error. Maybe you can post on Stackoverflow a new question?