# Spring Rest Authentication with a response

Tags: spring-security

I have setup a security context meant for REST. The configuration is as

```
<!-- authentication manager and password hashing -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" name="userAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetailsGetter" />

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    </beans:bean>

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <!-- web services -->
    <http use-expressions="true" pattern="/rest/**"
        disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <custom-filter ref="restProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="restProcessingFilter" class="com.myapp.auth.RestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/rest/login" />
    </beans:bean>
```

And I overrided the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` as

```
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication authentication = null;
        String username = request.getParameter("j_username");
        String password = request.getParameter("j_password");
        boolean valid = authService.authenticate(username, password);
        if (valid) {
            User user = updateLocalUserInfo(username);
            authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,
                    null, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        return authentication;
    }
```

The above authentication is working fine when I tried it with

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
String result = restClient.login("hq", "a1234567"); // RestTemplate.postForObject
```

The only thing left is the result from the authentication post (atm, result is null). How can I configure my security configuration in order to retrieve some result ? A flag or session ID will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I think best bet here would be [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html).

As this will only kick in if the authentication was successful.
You can generate some sort of UUID and set that in your response directly. I have used very similar approach for ReST Auth and have not hit any problems yet.

For detailed implementation **guide** please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930186/876142

Update for comment #1 :

You can get response just like any normal ReST request.

This is how I am sending back my Token as JSON

```
String tokenJsonResponse = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(authResponse);
httpResponse.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpResponse.getWriter().print(tokenJsonResponse);
```

Assuming you know how to use RestTemplate, rest is trivial.

Comment: How can I obtain the response in the `RestClient` ?

Comment: Where does the code should reside ? Am I required to perform additional request to get the response ?

Comment: No additional request needed, the code should reside in your custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler implementation.