# How to call extra parameter from login form into CustomAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I seen other post about this but still doesnt find appropriate answer.

My form submitted have three parameter instead of two.

Here my CustomAuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
    String userName = auth.getName().trim();
    String password = auth.getCredentials().toString().trim();
    String companyName ;


    if (userName.equals("admin") && password.equals("123456")) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        Authentication upat = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, password, grantedAuths);
        logger.info("{}:{}",userName,grantedAuths);
        return upat;

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
    return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(auth));
}
```

I want to get extra parameter from login form to authenticate the `companyName` in `CustomAuthenticationProvider`

How can I get the parameter from the login form?

Comment: Please show your spring security config ...

Comment: thanks for your intention,already got my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a research and major modified from another post , I came to solution by inject `AuthenticationDetailsSource` and `WebAuthenticationDetails` . So I will share the solution here:

First create new class for custom filter to get the parameter:

```
class ExtraParam extends WebAuthenticationDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final String company;

public ExtraParam(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    this.company = request.getParameter("company");
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return company;
}   
}
```

Then create the source class for injection :

```
class ExtraParamSource implements AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, ExtraParam> {

public ExtraParam buildDetails (HttpServletRequest context) {

return new ExtraParam(context);
}
}
```

After then, modified your spring security xml to identified the class and filter:

Add `authentication-details-source-ref="ExtraParam"` in your `<form-login` like this :

```
<form-login ... authentication-details-source-ref="ExtraParamSource"... />
```

And dont forget the bean :

```
<beans:bean id="ExtraParamSource" class="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.ExtraParamSource"/>
```

Then Finish! thats all. To get the parameter just use like this example below :

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{


@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
String userName = auth.getName().trim();
String password = auth.getCredentials().toString().trim();
String companyName = ((ExtraParam)auth.getDetails()).getCompanyName();

....
```

References :

1)[How to pass an additional parameter with spring security login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074308/how-to-pass-an-additional-parameter-with-spring-security-login-page)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the implementation I made, **it works with JAVA 17, Spring Security 6.1.4**

Having your form for Spring Security, add the necessary parameters, for example: **empresa**, n...

```
<form action="/login" method="post"  >

<label for="user">Usuario:</label>
<input name="username" placeholder="Usuario" type="text" maxlength="18" >

<label for="pass">Contraseña:</label>
<input name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" type="password">

<input id="empresa" name="empresa" type="hidden">

<div>
    <button type="submit">Ingresar</button>
</div>
```

1. Create class **CustomWebAuthenticationDetails.java**, "here you get the parameters that you send from the form, for example **empresa**, user-agent is an extra"

   ```
   public class CustomWebAuthenticationDetails extends WebAuthenticationDetails {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private final String empresa;
   private final String browser;

   public CustomWebAuthenticationDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
       super(request);
       // Params you need
       empresa = request.getParameter("empresa");
       browser = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
   }

   public String getEmpresa() {
       return empresa;
   }

   public String getBrowser() {
       return browser;
   }
   ```

}

2. Create class **CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource.java** (This class will be call in spring security config)
   `@Component
   public class CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource implements AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, WebAuthenticationDetails> {
   @Override
   public WebAuthenticationDetails buildDetails(HttpServletRequest context) {
   return new CustomWebAuthenticationDetails(context);
   }
   }`
3. In **security-config.xml** add Bean **"CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource.java"** and add reference in **"authentication-details-source-ref"**

   `<b:bean id="extraParamsLogin" class="gob.sep.login.controller.CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource">
   </b:bean>`

   ```
   <form-login
       login-page="/login.jsp"
       default-target-url="/home.jsp"
       authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true"
       authentication-details-source-ref="extraParamsLogin"
   />
   ```
4. I have **AuthenticationProvider.java** implements "AuthenticationProvider". In override method **authenticate()**, we get the parameters of the object **authentication.getDetails()** like this:

   `@Component
   public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{`

   @Override
   public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
   String user = authentication.getName();
   String pass = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
   CustomWebAuthenticationDetails extraParams = (CustomWebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();

   ```
   System.out.println("=>User: " + user);
   System.out.println("=>Pass: " + pass);
   System.out.println("IP explorador=> " + extraParams.getIp());
   System.out.println("Nombre explorador => " + extraParams.getBrowser());

   List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();

   SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
   authorities.add(authority);

   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, pass, authorities);

   return auth;
   ```

   }

   @Override
   public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
   return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
   }

}