# Issue while trying to retrieve additional parameter from login page using Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I've to use additional parameter in login page of Spring Boot based application which uses Spring Security for authentication. I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077700/812439) solution, but receive and error. Firstly I'll show the configuration:

Security config:

```
package org.aze.accountingprogram.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/lib/**").permitAll().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();

        // temporarily disabled
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }

}
```

Custom filter:

```
package org.aze.accountingprogram.config;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        final String projectId = request.getParameter("projectId");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("projectId", projectId);
        return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
    }

}
```

Custom filter is working. In debug mode, I see that value of `projectId` really is that value what was selected in dropdown list at the login page. So, I have one issue and one question.

When I run the application and click on submit button I receive the following error:

```
ERROR o.s.b.c.w.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage - Forwarding to error page from request [/login] due to exception [null]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93) ~[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.aze.accountingprogram.config.CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:22) ~[CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[LogoutFilter.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[HeaderWriterFilter.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[FilterChainProxy.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[FilterChainProxy.class:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[DelegatingFilterProxy.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[DelegatingFilterProxy.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[RequestContextFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[HttpPutFormContentFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[HiddenHttpMethodFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[CharacterEncodingFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120) [ErrorPageFilter.class:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [ErrorPageFilter.class:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95) [ErrorPageFilter$1.class:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [ErrorPageFilter.class:1.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) [catalina.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2403) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2392) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.14]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

I'm running it in Tomcat 8.0 (deployed as WAR file). Below is the main configuration:

```
package org.aze.accountingprogram;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean encodingFilter() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-8", true);
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegBean.setUrlPatterns(getRootPathUrls());
        filterRegBean.setFilter(encodingFilter);
        filterRegBean.setOrder(1);
        return filterRegBean;
    }

    private List<String> getRootPathUrls() {
        List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
        urlPatterns.add("/*");
        return urlPatterns;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```