# Spring Security - how to provide additional parameter to UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a need to provide an optional additional parameter to my implementation of Spring Security's `UserDetailsService`.

As a simple example, let's say I need to pass a Pet ID for the pet that belongs to the User.

Not all Users have pets, but if they do, my `Person` class that implements `UserDetails` has a Pet that needs to be retrieved upon login.

Here's what I tried thus far:

[How to pass an additional parameter with spring security login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074308/how-to-pass-an-additional-parameter-with-spring-security-login-page)

The problem with the accepted answer is it feels wrong/leaky for `UserDetailsService` implementation to couple in awareness of `HttpRequest` and `HttpSession`.

Other approaches I've looked at involve custom `AuthenticationDetails` and `AuthenticationDetailsSource`, but this feels wrong also, since the `UserDetailsService` seems like it should be responsible for a single thing (loading User Details), and the Pet would be part of those User Details.

I know I can get one of these approaches to work, but they don't feel clean.  Has anyone come up with a good approach on solving this problem?  Not looking for anyone to write code for me, just looking for a general approach.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think there maybe a misunderstanding as to the purpose of [UserDetails](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html). Looking at the Javadoc UserDetails is about how the user relates to the security apparatus of your application/system. As the method summary shows; getPassword, getUsername, getAuthorities, etc, essentially who is this person (authC) and what can they do (authZ). The loading of a user's pet information would be more of a business concern and should be handled in a separate service, PetService.doesUserHavePet(User) PerService.loadPet(User), not within your implementation of UseDetailsService which should be loading an users info from your organizations directory service and/or user store. I think the reason why you are finding every approach less then clean is you are trying to incorporate two concepts/responsibilities into a single class.